# How Can I count Html cell' in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

i'm using method to bind data from database to fill in PdfPTable
and i use this method to add data by cell

```
        dfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("header with colspan 3"));
        cell.BackgroundColor = Color.GRAY;
        cell.Colspan = 3;
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;           
        cell.Border = PdfBorderArray.BOOLEAN;
        cell.BorderColor = Color.RED;
        table.AddCell(cell);
```

How Can I count Html cell's in code behind from PdfPTable using ASP.net

Comment: Are you trying to set an index on the cell or count how many cells you have added or something completely different?

Comment: yes i'm try to just count how many cells so i could use it in other method to do customization for these cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var noOfCells = table.Rows.Select(r => r.GetCells()).Count();
```